# How can I search in a specific group with the Yammer API?

Tags: yammer

There is a Yammer [Search API](https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json), but it only returns results from all group in a Yammer network. Is there a way to search only a specific group?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an additional undocumented parameter `search_group=GROUP_ID`. This isn't documented and therefore isn't officially supported, so your mileage may vary.